# Unexpected string in JSON at position 86 at parse cant fix

Tags: javascript, json, discord, bots

{```

```
 "token":"token" //here have token him are a okey
 "prefix":"!" // its prefix him also erorr
```

//how to this fix(btv im can give file index.js
};

Comment: It's missing a comma, you need to fix whatever's _emitting_ that and claiming it's JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing a comma after "token." Also note that you cannot have comments in JSON, so if you have those in your source code take them out.

This should work:

```
{
 "token":"token",
 "prefix":"!"
}
```

Comment: New erorr invaild token

Comment: @user17202586 It sounds like you are not using the exact JSON I provided. If you edit your answer to show exactly what you are using we can probably find the issue.

Comment: If you have different questions you need to create a new question for that.